# Node Rest API issue with controller

Tags: node.js, rest, postman

I developed my node rest api as usual but this time it is showing some invalid error in controller.js file. The mongoose is not getting required. When I hit the API in postman, it gives the error as :

`{
    "error": {
        "message": "Tweets is not a constructor"
    }
}`

I even updated my packages for the same, but nothing seems to work. Here is the snippet of my **controller for tweets.js**:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Tweets = require('../models/tweets');

exports.get_all_tweets = (req, res, next) => {
    Tweets.find()
    .exec()
    .then(docs => {
        console.log(docs);
        res.status(200).json(docs);
    })       
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
          error: err
        });
      });
}

exports.create_tweets = (req, res, next) => {
    const tweetbody = req.body;
    tweetbody._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
    const tweet = new Tweets(tweetbody);
    tweet
    .save()
    .then(docs => {
        console.log(docs, 'Tweets');
        res.status(200).json(docs);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err, 'error found');
        res.status(500).json({
          error:err
        });
    });
```

The first mongoose line is appearing blank as shown in the screenshot:
[mongoose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNj3u.jpg)

**Model for tweets.js:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const tweetSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    time: { type: String},
    count: { type: Number}
});

module.export = mongoose.model('Tweets', tweetSchema);
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `.exec()` ?

Comment: @narayansharma91 It is returning a promise

Answer (score 0):

please check all path and add new keyword before schema initializing

**Model for tweets.js:**

```
const tweetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
```

Comment: I tried using it with 'new' keyword. With or without 'new' doesn't make much difference. In both cases, the new instance will be created eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `async/await`

```
exports.get_all_tweets = async (req, res, next) => {
    const result = await Tweets.find()
    res.status(200).json(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

module.exports with a 's' at the end :)

Comment: Damn! It was so silly of me for such a typo. Thanks a lot buddy for saving me. :)

Comment: I have already. But since I am less in reputations, my vote is not publicly displayed. :)